# Want to compare Key "SomeText" with its value than its value with new key "NewText" using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, cucumber

Feature: Given file Json is: Request Body
Given The json request data

```
{
   "Body" :{
      "SomeText": "12001BC851B3605EA",
    }
}
```

Response Body Json would be:

```
{
   "Body" : {
      "NewText": "12001BC851B3605EA",
    }
}
```

Want to compare Key "SomeText" with its value than its value with new key "NewText" using Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to ask a clear question, and format it in a way that users can understand, with all the relevant code and explanations. Cheers!

Comment: @Pooja i've attempted to clean up the formatting, but still not sure what you're asking

Comment: You can do like this `if(Body.SomeText == Body.NewText)`

Answer (score 0):

See how to compare two `json` object

```js
var rs1 = {
   "Body" :{
      "SomeText": "12001BC851B3605EA",
    }
}

var rs2 = {
   "Body" : {
      "NewText": "12001BC851B3605EA",
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
            if (rs1.Body.SomeText == rs2.Body.NewText) {
                alert("true")
                // Do something 
            } else {
                alert("false")
                // Do something 
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```